# Android - Integrate Your Library Codelessly to Display Views

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I have read that by having a provider on the library's manifest, you can integrate a library you create into the apps without forcing them to write any integration code.

How is this possible? Where would you get the reference to the context or the FragmentManager then in order to display a dialog or a button?

Comment: The first part of your question sounds like: [Get Context in Android library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45991963/295004), but you should quote/link the source where you believe you can display views (without some integration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have read that by having a provider on the library's manifest, you can integrate a library you create into the apps without forcing them to write any integration code.

Not really. It would be more accurate to phrase it as "by having a `<provider>` in the library's manifest, you can initialize a library without forcing app developers to write any initialization code".

Initialization != integration.

> How is this possible?

All registered `ContentProvider` instances get inititialized when the app's process starts, even before `onCreate()` of the `Application` gets called. Frequently, this is a bug (adding startup cost), but done correctly, it can be a feature (allowing libraries to self-initialize).

> Where would you get the reference to the context or the FragmentManager then in order to display a dialog or a button?

The app developer would call some API that you supply.

Comment: I see, so the app developer will have to call some API anyway. In this case, may I ask you how would you design the API if you wanted to show a view (Button, TextView, etc.) on every screen of the integrated app?

Comment: @DeveloperKurt: Off the top of my head, I have no idea, sorry.